# Проблема запушить проект на GitHub. Работаю в WebStorm

Tags: github, webstorm

Пытаюсь запушить проект но не получается из-за того, что когда копировал одна буква в имени пользователя не скопировалась, а сейчас не знаю как поменять все это
[image: Вместо "nimeshnin" должен быть "Animeshnik"]

Вместо "nimeshnin" должен быть "Animeshnik"

Comment: Попробуйте `git remote set-url <ИМЯ REMOTE> <ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ АДРЕС>`. PS: имена remote можно посмотреть командой `git remote`, скорее всего правильным будет вариант `origin`.

Comment: И, кстати, приведите, пожалуйста, полный вывод (лучше текстом).

Answer (score 0):

Главное меню - <kbd>Git</kbd> - <kbd>Manage remotes...</kbd> - Исправить на нужное.